# Help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry for the specificity of this question, but i've been up for 48h and my mind is probably void right now.

so, I have a table -> id|userid|card
where a user can have multiple cards

I just need to query the table to find the userid that have exactly 24 distinct cards (there are users with repeated cards).

Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID
FROM tableName
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 24
```

See [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

**Update:** to find users that have 24 distinct cards:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM (
    SELECT UserID
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY UserID, Card
) rs
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 24
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM tableName
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Card) = 24
```

Comment: thanks, that would definitely work, if i didn't mess up my question. Can you please look at my edit?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid FROM (
    SELECT userid, count(*) as cnt FROM some_table GROUP BY userid
) WHERE cnt = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
    ( select count(*) cnt,card from tablename group by card ) 
where cnt=24
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to find the users that have 24 cards, not the cards that have 24 users.